# cannot call status.place.country and status.place.name in twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

I found a weird problem while using tweepy to get tweets by streaming api.

That is, when I want to format the json output, here is the function:

```
def info_select(status, all_info={}):
    """
    select the info we need and wrap it by json format
    Return: a json obj all_info
    """
    # set the tweet id
    all_info["tweet_id_str"] = status.id_str
    # set the content of tweet
    all_info["tweet_text"] = status.text
    # set the time for tweet
    all_info["created_at"] = str(status.created_at)
    # set user id and screen_name
    all_info["user_id"] = status.user.id_str
    all_info["screen_name"] = status.user.screen_name
    # set the country & city
    all_info["country"] = status.place.country
    all_info["city_name"] = status.place.name
    # set the favorite_count
    all_info["favorite_count"] = str(status.favorite_count)
    # set the retweet_count
    all_info["retweet_count"] = str(status.retweet_count)

    json_obj = json.dumps(all_info)
    return json_obj
```

when I call "status.user.id_str", it do work and get the user id, also when calling"status.user.screen_name".

But, the code"status.place.country" or "status.place.name" will cause "NoneObject"exception.

But country and name are two attributes in Places obj!!!
Ref: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/places

Could you pls help me to call these two parameters?
Really thks~

Comment: Can you print the value of `status` received ?

Comment: @Satish Garg " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'country' " or "name"